# bean of JdbcTemplate in spring: reuse the same session for each request?

Tags: spring

I have the following bean defined in xml

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" >
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"></ref>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then in a spring mvc controller it we be used like:

```
@RestController
public class GenerateKey {
    final private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    final private AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate;
    final private String queueName;
    @Autowired
    public GenerateKey(@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate") JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,@Qualifier("keyRequestTemplate") AmqpTemplate rabbitMQTemplate,@Value("${keyRequestQueueName}") String queueName){
        this.jdbcTemplate=jdbcTemplate;
        this.rabbitMQTemplate =rabbitMQTemplate;
        this.queueName =queueName;
    }
```

My questions are:

1. For each request comes to this controller, will a new instance of `GenerateKey` be created or all request will reuse the same instance?
2. If use different instances, then when wire `JdbcTemplate`, will all of these instance share the same instance of JdbcTemplate or each instance has its own unique `JdbcTemplate`? since `JdbcTemplate` is not defined scope so the default is single meaning only one instance of `JdbcTemplate` will be created.
3. If #2 is valid, sharing the same `JdbcTemplate` meaning all request will use the same database connection? that means there is only one query could be run at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to question 1: Spring controllers are singletons. That means that only one instance of your `GenerateKey` class, which is a REST controller will be created (all requests will use that one instance).

Answer to question 2: You can safely reuse `JdbcTemplate`. Here is an excerpt from the JavaDoc of `JdbcTemplate`:

> Can be used within a service implementation via direct instantiation
>   with a DataSource reference, **or get prepared in an application context
>   and given to services as bean reference**. Note: The DataSource should
>   always be configured as a bean in the application context, in the
>   first case given to the service directly, in the second case to the
>   prepared template.

The highlighted text describes your use-case, which is perfectly valid.

The JavaDoc also mentions this:

> NOTE: An instance of this class is thread-safe once configured.

Which supports the previous statement. Once the instance is configured (Spring creates the instance and injects data source reference) you can safely use it concurrently in multiple places.

Answer to question 3: Typically your data source will have some connection pooling facility. That means that if multiple queries are called at once they will borrow unused connection from the connection pool.

Comment: Just for followers: on point 3, if you use Spring's standard `DriverManagerDataSource` (tempting because it's already in the classpath when you have `spring-jdbc` i.e. JdbcTemplate), [connections will **not** be reused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59886270/cant-alter-oracle-session-with-jdbctemplate)