# Can't alter Oracle session with JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, oracle18c

I need to change the NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS of my Oraclesession in my Spring-Standaloneapplication. I'm using JdbcTemplates:

```
logger.info("Setting NLS-Parameter.");
jdbcTemplate.execute("alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'");
logger.info(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'", String.class));
```

But it does not change:

```
Setting NLS-Parameter.
,.
```

I initialize the JdbcTemplate programatically:

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName(ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER);
dataSource.setUrl(url);
dataSource.setUsername(schema);
dataSource.setPassword(password);
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

All other statements are working perfectly. Just altering the session does not work. The Database is Oracle 18 Standart.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349409/spring-jdbctemplate-alter-session

Answer (score 1):

The [`DriverManagerDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) data source returns a new Connection from every getConnection call.

Thus, [`JdbcTemplate#execute(StatementCallback<T> action)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L371), which `JdbcTemplate#execute(final String sql)` and `JdbcTemplate#queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType)` ultimately both call, will get a [*newly* created connection](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L371) for each execution.

The `alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='.,'` statement changes `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` for the *session*, so only for the connection that executes the statement. The change won't have an effect on other connections.

Comment: As an immediate resolution, you could switch to using `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource` (passing `true` for the last constructor param `suppressClose`); assuming you don't need multiple concurrent connections